# Difference between normal setState call and call with callback/function as argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Code Snippet #1**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function DelayedCount() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("updating count...", count)
  }, [count])

  function handleClickAsync() {
    setTimeout(function delay() {
      setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
    }, 3000);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button onClick={handleClickAsync}>Increase async</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Code Snippet #2**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function DelayedCount() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("updating count...", count)
  }, [count])

  function handleClickAsync() {
    setTimeout(function delay() {
      setCount(count + 1); //UPDATED THIS PART OF CODE!!!
    }, 3000);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button onClick={handleClickAsync}>Increase async</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Edit on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-state-broken-forked-uezkd5)

Can someone explain why in code snippet #1, if I click 3 times quickly, the console log inside `useEffect` runs 3 times for each click?

But in code snippet #2, if I change the `setCount` inside `handleClickAsync` to be a simple state update (i.e. without callback function) like in the above code, the `useEffect` now only runs once even if I click 3 times.

As I understand, React should batch state updates in both cases. So why does it seem like the state was not batched in case 1?

Comment: nothing to do with batching, but with the fact that `count` is set to 1 3 times in your "snippet 2". The second and third of those times, it hasn't changed, so of course the effect that has `count` as its only dependency doesn't run again.

Comment: @RobinZigmond no that's not the case. If i click 3 times slowly within those 3 seconds, you'll notice that useEffect call happens exactly 3 seconds after the time when 3rd click happened, not the first click. Which means updates from first and second clicks were ignored and only third update leads to useEffect call. Seems like batching to me.

Comment: @D_S_X No, it does happen 3s after the first click. Add a timestamp to your logs to confirm.